# problem regarding packages installation in ubuntu

Tags: installation

I am new to ubuntu and cant find a solution to my simple question "do the new installation affects the installation of previously installed packages?". Can anybody solve my query or suggest me a suitable manual to clear my doubts. Please solve my query.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? Are you trying to reinstall ubuntu, upgrade it, or just install new packages?

Comment: i am just new to ubuntu . I had previously installed open cv library but wanted to be sure whether it will be fine to install open gl without affecting the installation of open cv.

Comment: Simply i just wanted to ask is it possible in ubuntu to install  packages without affecting individual packages . Please reply.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you are using the OpenCV Computervision libary.
It should behave nicely with other packages.
The Ubuntu packaging system will complain if a new package would conflict with an already installed one (provided both were installed as packages).

I looked it up (you can do that using a package manager like synaptic) and libopencv-core does not conflict with anything. So as long as you try it with the package manager/software center, you should be fine.

Hope this helps, 
Patrick

Comment: My pleasure. If this solved your problem just click the checkmark to accept the answer ;) Have fun with ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

when you installing ubuntu, in generally like any other OS, is gonna ask you befor installation start, for your choice, do you want to install and delete everything that you had, do you want to keep that and install ubuntu on new partition. so now choice is yours. ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply. My problem is regards the installation of new packages not regards ubuntu installation. I am asking that if i have previously installed something in terminal and i wanted to install new thing like new packages. Are the previous installations working affected by this new installation activity. activity.

Comment: oooh sorry for my mistake :D can you tell me what kind of packages you want to install?

Comment: Actually i an using open cv library (c library) but now wanted to start up with open gl (graphics library).

Comment: if i understand now, you want to remove cv and install gl, or what?

Comment: i dont want to remove open cv . I want that both the packages are there and the work fine .

Comment: look in your hard disk you have partitions, but every partition has subpartitions, not real partitions, i just like to call that in that way...every subpartition contains some application or anything you install on it, so you have installed cv on one subpartition, and gl will be installed on other, so thay can not affect each other, like any other software can not (of course if is not malware or virus) so install it without any risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation . This further cleared my doubt as i was unaware of the partitioning system used for installation process.

Comment: you are welcome. finally somebody can understand here my explanations :D so congratulations to you :D

Comment: Thanks, this was the only explanation i was loooking for. Good work. Keep it up.